# Is there a report in Google Analytics for visit duration for mobile only?

Tags: google-analytics, mobile

I recently improved the mobile experience of a site and I want to see if it has had an impact.

In Google Analytics, can I get a report on the visit duration limited to mobile devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Mobile Traffic" [Advanced Segment](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=108040) will allow you to see overall visit duration for your site, visit duration for content pages, visit duration by traffic source, and much more.

Comment: Cool, thank you. I did that as a Custom Segment, and there seems to be an identical one named Mobile Traffic in the Default Segments.

Comment: @Liam - Looks like they recently added it, don't recall seeing it when I checked to put together those instructions. Still, knowing how to create your own segments will serve you well.